# Sorting a dict by values inside an inner dict in Python

Tags: python, sorting

My apologies if I am using the incorrect terminology, as I'm a bit of a Python n00b when it comes to the proper descriptions for data structures.

I have a data structure that looks like this:

```
{
    u'COU': {'hl': 39, 'hw': 42, 'winPct': Decimal('0.5471698113207547169811320755'), 'al': 36, 'l': 72, 'w': 87, 'aw': 45}, 
    u'MIN': {'hl': 42, 'hw': 39, 'winPct': Decimal('0.3559322033898305084745762712'), 'al': 57, 'l': 114, 'w': 63, 'aw': 24}, 
    u'BOW': {'hl': 36, 'hw': 44, 'winPct': Decimal('0.5432098765432098765432098765'), 'al': 37, 'l': 74, 'w': 88, 'aw': 44}
}
```

I want to sort this data structure by the value in winPct inside the inner dict and searching online has revealed a dazzling array of advice that makes no sense to this raised-on-PHP developer.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: well, first of all, dicts have no order. You can, maybe, extract keys/values as a list and sort that

Comment: @varzan ordered dicts do exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't sort a dictionary, but you could convert the dictionary into a list of tuples with the form `(key, value)`.

```
sorted_d = sorted(d.iteritems(), key=lambda v: v[1]['winPct'])
```

To Reverse the sorting as per your comment use:

```
sorted_d = sorted(d.iteritems(), key=lambda v: v[1]['winPct'], reverse=True)
```

Comment: that worked but is from least to greatest, how would I sort them so that it's greatest to least?

Comment: @GrumpyCanuck:  Add `reverse = True` to the sorted call

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure is a dictionary, and dictionaries don't have an ordering on the associations inside them, so I'm going to interpret "sort this data structure" to mean "make a list containing the (key,values) pairs from this data structure". This may or may not be what you want. So, first of all, get those pairs:

```
pairs = d.items()
```

(note: this returns a list in Python 2; I think it returns something else in Python 3, for which you'd need to call `list()` explicitly to make it into something you could sort, or call `sorted` instead of `sort`). Now sort according to your criterion:

```
pairs.sort(key = lambda (k,v): v['winPct'])
```

and now `pairs` contains what (perhaps) you want.